# Account provisioning after installing sql server 2008

Tags: provisioning, account

im using windows server 2008, while installing sql server 2008, in account provisioning, i added current user. but now after installation, i added new user in windows. now the problem is in not able to login into sql server 2008.

so how do i add the new user in account provisioning in sql server 2008.

check the screenshot for more details
[image]

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a simple answer.

login windows using the username added in sql server

open sql server, login using windows authentication/sql authentication

goto Security->Login->right click and click on "New Login"

in new login window, click Search

enter your new window's username

click on checknames

click ok->ok

thats it.